# Creating a Sankey Diagram for an Org Chart

Tags: r, visualization, sankey-diagram, networkd3, orgchart

I have data in an excel table with two pertinent columns:
Employee Name and Manager Name.

I want to use networkD3 in R to create a Sankey Diagram with this data to show how our organization is split up. I'm a relative amateur with R but I've been able to produce Sankey charts by hard-coding each node. Is it possible to do this with the data I have?

```
    library(networkD3)
nodes = data.frame("name" = 
                     c(All_Employees$`Employee Name`))

links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
  All_Employees$`Employee Name`,All_Employees$`Manager Name`,1),
  byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))
names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize= 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

A Sankey diagram is probably **not** the best type of plot for this, but if you arrange your data into the proper format first, it will work...

```
All_Employees <- 
read.csv(header = T, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = F, check.names = F, 
text = "
Employee Name,Manager Name
Betty,
Tom,Betty
Bob,Betty
Mark,Tom
John,Tom
Sally,Bob")

node_names <- factor(sort(unique(as.character(unname(unlist(All_Employees))))))
nodes <- data.frame(name = node_names)
links <- data.frame(source = match(All_Employees$`Manager Name`, node_names) - 1, 
                    target = match(All_Employees$`Employee Name`, node_names) - 1,
                    value = 1)
links <- links[!is.na(links$source), ]

library(networkD3)
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use `diagonalNetwork()` which creates a tree diagram that is probably better suited...

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.tree)
library(networkD3)

All_Employees %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Manager Name`)) %>% 
  data.tree::FromDataFrameNetwork() %>%
  data.tree::ToListExplicit(unname = TRUE) %>%
  diagonalNetwork()
```

[image]

Or if you're using the dev version of `networkD3`, you can more easily use the new `treeNetwork()` function, which is has more customization (but is still buggy because it's still in dev)...

```
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)

All_Employees %>% 
  rename(nodeId = `Employee Name`, parentId = `Manager Name`) %>% 
  mutate(name = nodeId) %>% 
  treeNetwork(direction = "down", linkType = "elbow")
```

[image]